# How to display GIF as splash in visual studio c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, gif

I am trying to display a GIF picture as splash as starting of my small program in visual studio. I am really getting crazy. I looked it is possible in Qt IDE but I really need it in visual studio because my other code works only with visual studio. And yes I tried to convert my code for Qt giving me too many errors.

I have seen [this post.](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/27387/play-gif-using-gdi)

I am using GDI+ but still dunno how to simply display it instead of play and stop. It's okay even instead of splash to display a small form that plays the GIF file, can you guys give me a small code snippet in how to do it in c++?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an MFC window class that implements a splash screen using GDI Plus for displaying an (animated) GIF.

I've encapsulated everything inside a header file to simplify using it with your project.  Save it as an .h file (maybe "SplashWnd.h"), then include it wherever you want to set up the splash.  You app's `InitInstance` might be a good place to add it - something like this line (before any `DoModal` calls):

`SplashWnd splash(_T("Filname.gif"));`

The constructor can also take parameters for controlling the delay before auto-closing, and also specifying a function to call when the splash is closed.

The splash window has no border or caption - it appears only as the loaded image, floating on top of any other windows.  Its icon doesn't appear in the taskbar, and will close when its timeout expires, or the user clicks the window or presses a key.

```
#pragma once
#include <functional>
#include <afxwin.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"gdiplus.lib")

inline void ManageGdiPlusInit(bool release=false) {
    static int refcount = 0;
    static ULONG_PTR token;
    if(release) {
        if(--refcount == 0) { 
            Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown(token); 
        }
    } else if(++refcount == 1) {
        Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput startup_input;
        Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&token, &startup_input, 0);
}   }

inline void GdiPlusInit()    { ManageGdiPlusInit(false); }
inline void GdiPlusRelease() { ManageGdiPlusInit(true); }

namespace {
class SplashWnd : public CWnd {
protected:
    static CString WindowClass() {
        static CString name;
        if(name.IsEmpty()) {
            name = AfxRegisterWndClass(CS_DROPSHADOW, 0, (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(GRAY_BRUSH), 0);
        }
        return name;
    }

    Gdiplus::Image        *m_pImage;
    UINT                   m_FrameCount;
    unsigned char         *m_FrameDelayData;
    const UINT            *m_FrameDelays;
    UINT                   m_CurFrameIndex;
    UINT                   m_AnimationTimerId;
    UINT                   m_ExpireTimerId;
    CRect                  m_WindowRect;
    std::function<void()>  m_DismissCallback;

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()

    afx_msg void OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point) {
        DestroyWindow();
    }

    afx_msg void OnKeyDown(UINT nChar, UINT nRepCnt, UINT nFlags) {
        DestroyWindow();
    }

    afx_msg void OnDestroy() {
        if(m_AnimationTimerId != UINT(-1)) {
            KillTimer(m_AnimationTimerId);
        }
        if(m_ExpireTimerId != UINT(-1)) {
            KillTimer(m_ExpireTimerId);
        }
        if(m_DismissCallback) {
            m_DismissCallback();
        }
        CWnd::OnDestroy();
    }

    afx_msg void OnTimer(UINT nIDEvent) {
        if(nIDEvent == m_AnimationTimerId) {
            if(++m_CurFrameIndex >= m_FrameCount) {
                m_CurFrameIndex = 0;
            }
            DrawCurFrame();
            KillTimer(m_AnimationTimerId);
            m_AnimationTimerId = SetTimer(1, m_FrameDelays[m_CurFrameIndex], 0);
            return;
        }
        if(nIDEvent == m_ExpireTimerId) {
            DestroyWindow();
            return;
    }   }

    void PostNcDestroy() {
        if(m_DeleteSelf) {
            delete this;
        }
    }

    void DrawCurFrame() {
        Gdiplus::Graphics g(m_hWnd);
        GUID dim_select_id = Gdiplus::FrameDimensionTime;
        m_pImage->SelectActiveFrame(&dim_select_id, m_CurFrameIndex);
        g.DrawImage(m_pImage, 0, 0, m_WindowRect.Width(), m_WindowRect.Height());
    }

public:
    // set m_DeleteSelf to true if a SplashWnd is created with new, and you want it to
    // auto-delete itself when the window expires or is dismissed.
    bool m_DeleteSelf;

    // file_path    the gif file path
    // ExpireMs     the time, in milliseconds until the window automatically closes itself
    // WidthFactor  the fraction of the width of the primary display to use as the splash screen's width
    // HeightFactor the fraction of the height of the primary display to use as the height
    // If WidthFactor or HeightFactor are 0, the original image aspect ratio is preserved
    // If both are 0, the original image size, in pixels is used
    SplashWnd(CString file_path, DWORD ExpireMs=2000, double WidthFactor=0.4, double HeightFactor=0) {
        GdiPlusInit();

        m_pImage = new Gdiplus::Image(file_path);

        // Set up an array of frame times for animated images
        UINT dimension_count = m_pImage->GetFrameDimensionsCount();

        GUID dimension_id;
        m_pImage->GetFrameDimensionsList(&dimension_id, 1);
        m_FrameCount = m_pImage->GetFrameCount(&dimension_id);
        UINT frame_delay_size = m_pImage->GetPropertyItemSize(PropertyTagFrameDelay);

        m_FrameDelayData = new unsigned char[frame_delay_size];
        Gdiplus::PropertyItem* frame_delay_item = reinterpret_cast<Gdiplus::PropertyItem*>(m_FrameDelayData);
        m_pImage->GetPropertyItem(PropertyTagFrameDelay, frame_delay_size, frame_delay_item);
        m_FrameDelays = reinterpret_cast<const UINT*>(frame_delay_item->value);

        // Figure out the size and location of the splash window
        int primary_width  = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXFULLSCREEN);
        int primary_height = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYFULLSCREEN);

        int splash_width  = int(primary_width * WidthFactor);
        int splash_height = int(primary_height * HeightFactor);

        if(splash_width == 0) {
            if(splash_height == 0) {
                splash_width  = m_pImage->GetWidth();
                splash_height = m_pImage->GetHeight();
            } else {
                splash_width = primary_width * splash_height / primary_height;
            }
        } else if(splash_height == 0) {
            splash_height = primary_height * splash_width / primary_width;
        }

        int l = (primary_width - splash_width) / 2;
        int t = (primary_height - splash_height) / 2;
        int r = l + splash_width;
        int b = t + splash_height;

        m_WindowRect.SetRect(
            (primary_width  - splash_width)  / 2,
            (primary_height - splash_height) / 2,
            (primary_width  + splash_width)  / 2,
            (primary_height + splash_height) / 2);

        // WS_EX_TOPMOST makes the window cover up other, regular windows
        // WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW prevents an icon for this window in the taskbar
        // WS_POPUP prevents caption and border from being drawn
        CreateEx(WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW, WindowClass(), _T("Splash"), WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUP, m_WindowRect, 0, 0);

        // Show the first frame
        m_CurFrameIndex = 0;
        DrawCurFrame();

        // Set up the frame-flipping animation timer
        m_ExpireTimerId = m_AnimationTimerId = UINT(-1);
        if(m_FrameCount > 1) {
            m_AnimationTimerId = SetTimer(1, m_FrameDelays[m_CurFrameIndex], 0);
        }
        // Set up the expiration timer
        if(ExpireMs != INFINITE) {
            m_ExpireTimerId = SetTimer(2, ExpireMs, 0);
        }

        m_DeleteSelf = false;
    }

    // Constructor which takes a callback function which will be called when the splash window closes
    template <typename F>
    SplashWnd(CString file_path, DWORD ExpireMs, double WidthFactor, double HeightFactor, F DismissCallback)
        : SplashWnd(file_path, ExpireMs, WidthFactor, HeightFactor)
    {
         m_DismissCallback = DismissCallback;
    }

    ~SplashWnd() {
        delete [] m_FrameDelayData;
        delete m_pImage;
        GdiPlusRelease();
    }
};

// Message map, usually in an implementation file, but here encapsulated inside the header
// using an anonymous namespace to prevent possible ODR problems.
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(SplashWnd, CWnd)
    ON_WM_KEYDOWN()
    ON_WM_LBUTTONDOWN()
    ON_WM_TIMER()
    ON_WM_DESTROY()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

}
```